# What is the smartest way to let Google Maps canvas use 100% of remaining height

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]
Please see the above screenshot. On this web page I have a header consisting of 3 levels (green, light brown, dark brown), followed by a Google Map. The map is zoomed in on a location (country USA in this case).

The problem I have is that the map centering (vertically) is off by the same amount of pixels as the header. The canvas is set to 100% height, and so is the html and the body element. As I do not want a scrollbar in the viewport, overflow is set to hidden on the body element.

By temporarily disabling the overflow rule, you can see that the map overflows the viewport, which makes sense, since it begins below the header and uses 100% of the entire viewport. Thus it really is 100% + height of header.

What I want, however, is for the map to have a height that is equal to 100% of the height of the total viewport minus the height of the header. As the headers height is dynamic and depends on several factors, my question is what the smartest way is to accomplish this?

I guess Javascript can do the trick but I'm hoping we have better ways now? I'm looking for a robust solution.

Edit: live example:
http://www.jungledragon.com/wildlifemap/US

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: @geocodezip Which part are you looking for specifically? I think I shared all relevant parts already. This is the canvas CSS: #map_canvas { width:100%; height:100%; border:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden; } , for the rest, the html and body are set to 100%.

Comment: Please put the minimal complete CSS required to demonstrate the issue in the question. A [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best.

Comment: @geocodezip I've edit the question to add the live page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use conflicting absolute positions. The map div will have css similar to:

```
#mapcanvas {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 188px; /* this is to account for your header */
  bottom: 0;
}
```

See the Dynamic Map Height header in my [Developing for Mobile Devices Post](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/)

Comment: Thank you for responding. What if the header is of a dynamic height? Set that top using JS?

Comment: Yes - `top` via JavaScript would be the way to go.

Comment: Excellent, I have gotten it to work perfectly with only a few lines of code: function positionMap(elem) {
 
 var mapOffset = elem.position().top;
 $("#map_canvas").css({ 
  "height" : "auto",
    "position" : "absolute",
    "top" : mapOffset,
    "bottom" : "0"
 });
 return true;
}